# Last digit of a sum of powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

let $k = 1^1+2^2+...+2021^{2021}+2022^{2022}$

what is the last digit of $k$?

I've tried isolating a couple of terms, more specifically the ones that shared the same last digit, as such I've noted $10$ sums from $1$ to $10$:

$$S_1=1^1+11^{11}+..+2021^{2021}$$

$$S_2=2^2+12^{12}+...+2022^{2022}$$ and so on

From here I've basically tried to say the last digit of these sums would be equal with the following:

$$U(S_1) = 1^1 + 1^{11} + ... + 1^{2021}$$

$$U(S_2) = 2^2 + 2^{12} + ... + 2^{2022}$$

$$U(S_3) = 3^3 + 3^{13} + ... + 3^{2013}$$

Thus I'm not sure how to proceed from here, nor if my reasoning is even remotely correct.

Comment: Hint:  first argue that the sequence $\{n^n\pmod {10}\}$ is perdiodic $\pmod {20}$.

Comment: This question exists for (almost) any year after $2000$. See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067013/what-is-the-remainder-of-112233-20202020-if-divided-by-10?noredirect=1), or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051872/what-is-the-unit-digit-of-112233-20182018?noredirect=1&lq=1).